# Subscription triggered only once after error

Tags: rxjs

I'm a rookie in rxjs, and I'm trying to figure out what happened in the following code.

Indeed, in order to illustrate the idea, I prepare two simple promises (resolvePromise and rejectPromise), one resolves a promise, and the other rejects. 
A "Subject" instance is used to trigger these two promises (piped with mergeMap and forkJoin). At the end, two separates instructions (source$.next('xxx')) are added, hoping to trigger the subscription twice.

But finally, only the first "source$.next('1')" triggers the subscription, and the next "source$.next('2')" seems to do nothing.

I guess this behavior is caused by the reject promise, which literally "throws an exception".
But I'm wondering how can I fix this code, so that the second "source$.next('2')" will also trigger the subscription.

Thanks a lot

```
import { of,forkJoin,Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

const resolvePromise = val =>
  new Promise(resolve => resolve(`resolve value: ${val}`));

const rejectPromise = err =>
  Promise.reject(`reject error: ${err}`);

const source$ = new Subject();

source$
  .pipe(mergeMap(val => {
    return forkJoin([
      resolvePromise(val), 
      rejectPromise(val)
      ]);
  }))
  .subscribe(
     console.log, 
     console.error
  );

  source$.next('1');
  source$.next('2');
```

---

### Update

Based on suggestion given by Andrei Gătej below, in order to overcome this problem, I chose to pipe a catchError after the forkJoin, and place the error handling inside.

```
source$.pipe(
  mergeMap(val => {
    return forkJoin([
      resolvePromise(val),
      rejectPromise(val)
    ])
      .pipe(
        catchError(err => {
          // your error handling business logic
          console.error(err);
          return empty();
        })
      );
  }))
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> reject promise, which literally "throws an exception"

I'd say you're right, judging by how RxJS handles promises internally:

```js
promise.then(
  (value) => {
    if (!subscriber.closed) {
      subscriber.next(value);
      subscriber.complete();
    }
  },
  (err: any) => subscriber.error(err) // !
)
```

[Source](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/util/subscribeToPromise.ts#L12).

What's also worth mentioning is that, as you can see from the snippet above, as soon as the promise resolves for the first time, that **resolved value** and a `complete` notification will be passed along.

The `complete` part is very important for the `forkJoin` operator.

`forkJoin` subscribes to all the provided observables and **waits** until all complete. It will send an array with values **only if** the observables would have **emitted** at **least once**.

When one observable emits an `error` notification, `forkJoin` will immediately send that `error` notification further in the chain.

---

Here's my approach:

```js
ource$
  .pipe(mergeMap(val => {
    return forkJoin([
      resolvePromise(val), 
      from(rejectPromise(val)).pipe(catchError(err => of(err)))
      ]);
  }))
  .subscribe(
     console.log, 
     console.error
  );
```

We're using `from` so that we can *intercept* that promise error early, which allows us to use `catchError` and use an observable that will send a value and then a `complete` notification(`of(err)`).

Comment: Hi Andrei, thanks for the advice. Your suggestion does work in my case.
Followed by your idea, I'm wondering whether it could also be a solution to do things like this : 

(sorry for the code style in the comment)


  source$
  .pipe(mergeMap(val => {
    return forkJoin([
      resolvePromise(val), 
      rejectPromise(val)
      ])
      .pipe(catchError(err=>{
        console.error(err);
        return empty();
      }))
      
      ;
  }))
  .subscribe(
     console.log
  );

Comment: I mean, we place the error handling in the catchError func after the forkJoin. So that we don't need to check in  subscription, whether we got an error, or a normal result.

Comment: If source$ is a subject and/or as long is does not complete, I think this should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

you need to resubscribe via `retry` or `repeat`.

```js
import { of,forkJoin,Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

const resolvePromise = val =>
  new Promise(resolve => resolve(`resolve value: ${val}`));

const rejectPromise = err =>
  Promise.reject(`reject error: ${err}`);

const source$ = new Subject();

source$.pipe(
  mergeMap(val => forkJoin([
    resolvePromise(val), 
    rejectPromise(val)
  ])),
  catchError(() => EMPTY),
  repeat(),
).subscribe(
  console.log, 
  console.error
);

source$.next('1');
source$.next('2');
```

Comment: Hi satanTime, thanks for your advice. "retry" does several more attempts to solve the forkJoin, but, if one of the promises / observables keeps to fail, business rule check failed for instance, no matter how many times we retry, the result will stay the same.

Comment: Aha, I see, do you use `Subject` in your code? I've updated example to use `repeat`.